# Configure traffic pass-through except for local domain in apache

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm writing a webapp that requires a domain name to work properly. Thus in the hosts file, I set

## /etc/hosts

local.exampledomain.com 127.0.0.1

This works when I access the webapp from my browser.

Now, I'm trying to debug external mobile devices' behavior for my development app. I don't have access to a hosts file to force mobile devices to associate my local domain with my development server, but I can force them to treat my development server ip and a port (let's say 8888) as a proxy.

As a result, I want to find a way to configure my server allow all traffic sent to port 8888 to pass through it to its intended destination as if the mobile device in question weren't hitting my server, unless the mobile device attempts to hit a domain that matches the local domain in my hosts file. I have looked up apache configurations to duplicate this behavior, but I'm confused as to how to get it set up exactly to fit the needs described. Does anyone know how I might go about this problem?
Thanks,
- Daniel

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
  #ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
  ServerName localhost

  local.exampledomain.com http://0.0.0.0:3000 #forward traffic to my app
  http://192.168.1.1 #forward rest of traffic to default gateway
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. set on correct way in /etc/hosts. it should be

   127.0.0.1 host.domain host
2. set FQDM in clause ServerName
3. Set reverse proxy in virtual host